# How do I add an #ajax callback to File field form widget?

Tags: ajax, files

I have a content type with a file field: **field_file_field** . I want to attach a custom `#ajax` callback to the widget which will execute after file upload.

I have tried with:

```
$ajax_settings = array(
      'callback' => 'some_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => "default-wrapper",
      'method' => 'change',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    );

// All of those 3 I have tried.
$form['field_file_field']['#ajax'] = $ajax_settings;
$form['field_file_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#ajax'] = $ajax_settings;
$form['field_file_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#ajax'] = $ajax_settings;
```

Without success. Any idea ?
I want to change another file in the edit form when upload file.

Comment: there's no `change` method. Perhaps you meant to put that as `event`? Also, as to your main question, take a look at the core file module (file.field.inc specifically). There's a `#process` function that gets added on the file widget, which changes the #ajax array's values, effectively after everytime you upload an image. So you may need to add your own `#process` function into that array, and add your `#ajax` there. I've never done this before though. Hence just commenting.

Comment: Oh and you should probably use [`hook_field_widget_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7.x) to do the above (comment) instead of plain hook_form_alter

Comment: Can I add additional submit handler for Submit file button and somehow to update another field with javascript ?